# How can I refresh tablelayout within fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tablelayout

I am new to Android development. I removed unnecessary code here, but the call to the Rest API has no issues. I have a fragment here that has a tablelayout within. A call is made to a Rest API in the async task, which is then supposed to insert the retrieved data into the table and refresh it. The problem is, that the table does not display the data after it is received. Can someone please point me in the right direction into how to resolve this? Thanks!

```
public class TransactionsFragment extends Fragment {
    final String urlString = "https:/exampleurl.net/restapi/Handler.ashx";
    String cnoKey = "com.example.app.saveCredentials.cno";
    String aliasnameKey = "com.example.app.saveCredentials.aliasname";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    LayoutInflater inflaterGlobal;
    ViewGroup containerGlobal;

    List<String> recids;
    List<String> folders;
    List<String> whotos;
    List<String> directions;
    List<String> documents;
    List<String> thedates;

    View rootView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transactions, container, false);
        inflaterGlobal = inflater;
        containerGlobal = container;

        TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String aliasname = prefs.getString(aliasnameKey, null);

        new TestAsync(aliasname, "", getActivity()).execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
    {
        private String aliasname;
        private String password;
        private String value; //success value
        private String recid; //success recid
        private String folder;
        private String whoto;
        private String direction;
        private String document;
        private String thedate;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private Activity activity;

        public TestAsync(String aliasname, String password, Activity activity) {
            super();
            this.password = password;
            this.aliasname = aliasname;
            this.activity = activity;
        }
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            System.out.println("PreExecute");
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);

        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {

                JSONObject result = GetTranReport(aliasname, "False", "1", "03", "2015");


                recids = new ArrayList<>();
                folders = new ArrayList<>();
                whotos = new ArrayList<>();
                directions = new ArrayList<>();
                documents = new ArrayList<>();
                thedates = new ArrayList<>();


                JSONObject jsonObject;
                JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("Value");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length()-1; i++) {
                    System.out.println("i = " + i);
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println("recid = " + jsonObject.getString("recid"));
                    recids.add(jsonObject.getString("recid"));
                    folders.add(jsonObject.getString("folder"));
                    whotos.add(jsonObject.getString("whoto"));
                    directions.add(jsonObject.getString("direction"));
                    documents.add(jsonObject.getString("document"));
                    thedates.add(jsonObject.getString("thedate"));
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "You are at PostExecute";
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... a) {
            System.out.println("Progress Update" + a[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //handleLogin(value);
            System.out.println("" + result);
            View rootView = inflaterGlobal.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transactions, containerGlobal, false);
            //getActivity().recreate();

            TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

            prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String aliasname = prefs.getString(aliasnameKey, null);
            System.out.println("carrying out table creation");
            if (whotos.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < whotos.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("" +i);
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
                    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv.setText(whotos.get(i));
                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv2.setText(documents.get(i));
                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv3.setText(directions.get(i));
                    TextView tv4 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv4.setText(thedates.get(i));
                    row.addView(tv); //TP name
                    row.addView(tv2); //document type
                    row.addView(tv3); //direction
                    row.addView(tv4); //date

                    ll.addView(row, i+3);
                }
                ll.invalidate();
                ll.refreshDrawableState();
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Here is the fragment_transactions.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Transaction Report"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TP"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/doc"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Doc"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dir"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Direction"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- draw a red line -->
        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I wanted to add that the table loop previously worked when called from within OnCreateView when adding test data. I wanted to call this from within the AsyncTask as then it's easier to call it this way after the async task has completed.

Comment: You are creating a new View but not using it. since changing a fragment layout after creation looks not possible, can you post your fragment_transactions.xml so im able to tell you what you need to do?

Comment: I added the XML for fragment_transactions, so hopefully this can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
public class TransactionsFragment extends Fragment {
    final String urlString = "https:/exampleurl.net/restapi/Handler.ashx";
    String cnoKey = "com.example.app.saveCredentials.cno";
    String aliasnameKey = "com.example.app.saveCredentials.aliasname";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    LayoutInflater inflaterGlobal;
    ViewGroup containerGlobal;

    List<String> recids;
    List<String> folders;
    List<String> whotos;
    List<String> directions;
    List<String> documents;
    List<String> thedates;

    View rootView;
    TableLayout ll;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transactions, container, false);
        inflaterGlobal = inflater;
        containerGlobal = container;

        ll = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String aliasname = prefs.getString(aliasnameKey, null);

        new TestAsync(aliasname, "", getActivity()).execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        private String aliasname;
        private String password;
        private String value; //success value
        private String recid; //success recid
        private String folder;
        private String whoto;
        private String direction;
        private String document;
        private String thedate;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private Activity activity;

        public TestAsync(String aliasname, String password, Activity activity) {
            super();
            this.password = password;
            this.aliasname = aliasname;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            System.out.println("PreExecute");
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);

        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {

                JSONObject result = GetTranReport(aliasname, "False", "1", "03", "2015");


                recids = new ArrayList<>();
                folders = new ArrayList<>();
                whotos = new ArrayList<>();
                directions = new ArrayList<>();
                documents = new ArrayList<>();
                thedates = new ArrayList<>();


                JSONObject jsonObject;
                JSONArray jsonArray = result.getJSONArray("Value");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println("i = " + i);
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println("recid = " + jsonObject.getString("recid"));
                    recids.add(jsonObject.getString("recid"));
                    folders.add(jsonObject.getString("folder"));
                    whotos.add(jsonObject.getString("whoto"));
                    directions.add(jsonObject.getString("direction"));
                    documents.add(jsonObject.getString("document"));
                    thedates.add(jsonObject.getString("thedate"));
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "You are at PostExecute";
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... a) {
            System.out.println("Progress Update" + a[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //handleLogin(value);
            System.out.println("" + result);

            prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String aliasname = prefs.getString(aliasnameKey, null);
            System.out.println("carrying out table creation");
            if (whotos.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < whotos.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("" + i);
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(activity);
                    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv.setText(whotos.get(i));
                    TextView tv2 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv2.setText(documents.get(i));
                    TextView tv3 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv3.setText(directions.get(i));
                    TextView tv4 = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv4.setText(thedates.get(i));
                    row.addView(tv); //TP name
                    row.addView(tv2); //document type
                    row.addView(tv3); //direction
                    row.addView(tv4); //date

                    ll.addView(row, i + 3);
                }
                ll.invalidate();
                ll.refreshDrawableState();
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue. It just comes up blank.

Comment: @JordanJohnson I dont think so, because I tried with this code.

Comment: I had copied the code as is, but changed the return null to instead return rootView and this did resolve the issue. It is now working correctly, thank you!

Comment: @JordanJohnson thanks buddy for letting me know my issue.